# Create option values from JSON AJAX response using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, json

This is the input:

```
data = [
    {"localidad_cve":"1","localidad_nombre":"AZCAPOTZALCO"},
    {"localidad_cve":"10","localidad_nombre":"CRUZ BLANCA"},
    {"localidad_cve":"1","localidad_nombre":"VENUSTIANO CARRANZA"}
]
```

What i am looking for is this:

```
<option value="1">AZCAPOTZALCO</option>
<option value="10">CRUZ BLANCA</option>
<option value="1">VENUSTIANO CARRANZA</option>
```

How can i do that using jQuery?

Answer (score 3):

Fairly easy, loop, build, append:

```
var opts = "";
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    opts += "<option value='" + data[i].localidad_cve + "'>" + data[i].localidad_nombre + "</option>";
}
$("#yourSelect").append(opts);
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop and build:

```
var $options = [];
for(var a = 0, len = data.length; a < len; a++) {
    $options.push($('<option />', { "value": data[a].localidad_cve, "text": data[a].localidad_nombre }));
}
$('select').append($options);
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/pqMWh/1/)**